# Nautilus not saving online forms alphabetically

Tags: nautilus, file-sorting

Nautilus used to save downloaded forms and such in alphabetic order; or at least it listed it as an option. Now all I can see is 'Size', 'Type' and 'Modified'. There is now no 'A-Z', except when opening a file from the Home directory.
I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 on a desktop.

Comment: What do you mean by saving? You mean save file dialog?

Comment: Yes. Anything  Internet based file download, i when I get to to choose a folder but they don't allow me to chhe

Comment: Post a screenshot of the sorting options

Comment: I did, but don't see a method of uploading  it. As an example, let's say I'm on a site and decide to download an  available PDF. I see all my folders, but I have subfolders and sub-subfolder, one being my clients' folders. That folder (Clients) is randomly sorted and there is to A-Z option. This started with an upgrade to 23.04.

Comment: I did not see anything in dconfig to change anything in Nautilus. I'm not the best at bashing but I can follow instructions.

Comment: I can't find any sorting options that is similar to what you're describing. Please edit the post and click on the image icon above the editor and upload a screenshot.

Comment: Yesterday I changed the icon size in Nautilus to small. Today I downloaded two documents from Service Canada and the usual random sorting occurred, but the icons were bigger, while they remain the same small size when locally accessed . It has to be related.

Comment: I've also noticed that when i change a default application in 23.04 it doesn't stick and gas to be done with 'open with' each time. I have several files stored on my WIndows partition that once changed, they stay changed. I do not see an icon above the editor. I see five icons on the top left of this page but not related to uploading.